# An exception occurs when spark converts a json string to a HashMap in spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, serialization

there is no problem in the local environment, but a exception occur when performing spark submit.

The approximate code is as follows

```
class Test extends Serializable {
     def action() = {
         val sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
         val rdd1 = sc.textFile(.. )
         val rdd2 = rdd1.map ( logline => {
             //gson
             val jsonObject  jsonParser.parse(logLine).getAsJsonObject
             //jackson
             val jsonObject = objectMapper.readValue(logLine,classOf[HashMap[String,String]])
             MyDataSet ( parsedJson.get("field1"), parsedJson.get("field2"),...)              
         }                                  
     }
}
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
               ensureSerializable(ClosureCleanser. scala:444)..
               ........
               ........
               caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException : com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.modifiers.ScalaTypeModifier
```

I have used both gson and jackson libraries.

Isn't this a problem that can be solved just by inheriting from serializable ?

Comment: Where is `objectMapper` (or `jsonParser`) defined? Is it a `val` member on the class somewhere? Try making it `lazy`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it was a different matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception `NotSerializableException` is pretty self explanatory. Your task is not serializable. Spark is a parallel computing engine. The driver (where your main program is executed) ships the transformations you want to make on the RDD (the code written inside `map` functions) to executors where they are executed. Therefore those transformations need to be serializable. In your case, `jsonParser` and `objectMapper` are created on the driver. To use them inside a transformation, spark tries to serialize them and fails because they are not serializable. That's your error. I don't know which one is not serializable, maybe both.

Let's take an example and see how we can fix it.

```scala
// let's create a non serializable class
class Stuff(val i : Int) {
    def get() = i
}
// we instantiate it in the driver
val stuff = new Stuff(4)

//this fails "Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Stuff"
val result = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2,3)).map( x => (x, stuff.get)).collect
```

To fix it let's create the object inside the transformation

```scala
val result = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2,3))
    .map( x => {
        val new_stuff = new Stuff(4)
        (x, new_stuff.get)
    }).collect
```

It works, but obviously, creating the object for every record can be quite expensive. We can do better with `mapPartition` and create the object only once per partition:

```scala
val result = sc.parallelize(Seq(1, 2,3))
    .mapPartitions(part => {
         val new_stuff = new Stuff(4)
         part.map( x => (x, new_stuff.get))
    }).collect
```

Comment: Tahnk you. You are my teacher.. I knew the concept of a spark driver, but i didn't care at all when I 'm programming.
Anyway. the issue has been resolved. I wish you were my senior colleague .. haha